# Qual é o nome deste objeto parecido com um telefone fixo?

Tags: palavra-para-ideia, nomes

Gostaria de saber qual o nome deste objeto em português (de Portugal preferivelmente, se for diferente, claro):

[image]

Não é um telefone e não se chama campainha, mas é usado para responder à campainha de dentro das casas e mais geralmente dos apartamentos, e encontra-se normalmente "colado" ou pendurado as paredes.

Em italiano este objeto chama-se *citofono*.

Comment: Tinhas *objecto* (grafia antiga) num sítio, e *objeto* (grafia nova) noutro. Pus *objeto* em todo o lado, sem saber se tens alguma preferência...

Comment: Pois, em Portugal ninguém pronuncia esse ***c***, mas há pessoal muito apegado à grafia antiga. Portanto uma pessoa nestas situações nunca sabe.

Comment: Em pt-BR é interfone .

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A palavra com que eu estou familiarizado em Portugal é ***intercomunicador***. Vários dicionários, brasileiros e portugueses, indicam com o mesmo significado *intercomunicador* e ***interfone***, mas os dicionários brasileiros parecem dar preferência a *interfone* (vê [Dicio](https://www.dicio.com.br/intercomunicador/) e [Aulete](http://www.aulete.com.br/interfone)). E eu deixo aqui o [Priberam (baseado em Portugal)](http://www.priberam.pt/dlpo/intercomunicador), que dá exatamente a mesma definicão para *interfone* e *intercomunicador:*

> 1. Circuito fechado de comunicação telefónica entre diferentes zonas ou compartimentos (de prédio, navio, comboio, etc.).
> 2. Aparelho telefónico que permite essa comunicação